# Trigger IsPressed property of button with code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a menu with buttons. When a user presses a button it will execute the same method until he releases the button. In other words I start a task on MouseDown and I stop that task on MouseUp.

here is my button

```
<Button
    x:Name="pushButton"
    Focusable="False"
    Content="{Binding ButtonLabel}"        
    PreviewMouseDown="StartTask"
    PreviewMouseUp = "StopTask"        
 />
```

**I want to be able to press the button with a keyboard shortcut** As a result I have subscribed to the main window event `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewKeyUp`. Those events get fired correctly and I am able to start the task when the key is down and stop the task when the key is up. **I will like to have the button change its state to as pressed so that the user can see it visually** . How can I change the state of the button to pressed with c# ?

---

### Edit

I ended up changing its IsPressed value via reflection because the setter is private as:

```
typeof(Button).GetMethod("set_IsPressed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(BtnInstance , new object[] { true });
```

Comment: can you set the `IsPressed` property in the code behind?

Comment: IsPressed does not have a set method I can only read it :(

Comment: I think, you need [`ToggleButton`](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.ru/2011/12/wpf-toggle-button.html) to do this. He has IsChecked property, which can have three states: true, false and null.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev that is a good idea. You could also create your own button with a bool property and have a datatrigger on that button that would set the style to and from pressed style.  Ill try and put something together and post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you part of the way there. In VS2013, I right clicked the button, choose Edit Template then Edit a Copy..  Then in the style it created there was a "RenderPressed" property in the ControlTemplate that it created.  It's bound to IsPressed by default, but I changed the binding to a bool in my ViewModel and i was able to toggle the button.